# Density Theorem and Limit Proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I'm new to proof writing and have trouble understanding hoe to structure or get proofs started. An example proof that my teacher left as practice is below. Any suggestions? Of course, I know I must use the Density Theorem I am just not sure how.

Prove that given x ∈ ℝ there is a sequence r ∈ ℚ such that r -> ℚ as n -> ∞.

Comment: Your teacher's practice problem was " Prove that give $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists a sequence $r_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $r_n\rightarrow x$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$". Do you understand the differences?

Comment: @yanko To be more precise, you should probably write a sequence $(r_n)\subset \mathbb Q$ such that $r_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: @Liza are you allowed to use that in every $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ there is a rational number?

Comment: Oh yes, I do understand why it needs to be rn. Yes I believe so @Epiousios

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you are allowed to use that in every $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of a real number there are rational numbers.

Let $x\in \mathbb R$. Because $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R,$ for any $n\in \mathbb N$ we can find $r_n\in \mathbb Q$ such that $|r_n-x|<1/n$. Then for any $n,$
$$0\le|r_n-x|\le 1/n,$$
so that $|r_n-x|\to 0,$ as $n\to\infty$ by the Squeeze Theorem. That means that $r_n\to x,$ as $n\to \infty.$

Comment: I understand most of that. Except, where does the 1/n come from?

Comment: The $1/n$ is just a convenient sequence that converges to zero.  You could also take $1/n^2$ or $2^{-n}.$